# Matrix inequality for a sum of products of matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A,W \in M(n \times n, \mathbb{R})$ be two real $n$-dimensional matrices such that $A$ is diagonal and $W$ is off-diagonal.

Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix with only $0$ or $1$ entries on the diagonal. (There are $2^n$ such matrices).

Let $\max eig|\cdot|$ be the absolute value of the maximal eigenvalue of a matrix.

My question is the following: Is it true that
$$\max eig|A+W \cdot D|\leq \max eig|A+W |?$$

Comment: What do you mean by a “maximal eigenvalue norm”? The complex field is not ordered. If you mean spectral radius, it is not a norm.

Comment: Operator $2$-norm is probably the most straightforward way to interpret this IMO since it equals the spectral radius for normal matrices.

Comment: You are right, I will rephrase the question. I am actually interested in the maximal eigenvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false.

Consider the diagonal matrix $A$ and the off-diagonal matrix $W$ such that

$$ A + W = \begin{pmatrix}4 & -6\\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$
whose eigenvalues are $2$ and $1$.

Then for $D = 0$ we have

$$ \max \vert eig(A + WD)\vert  = \max \vert eig(A) \vert  = \max \vert a_{ii}\vert 
 = 4 > 2 = \max eig(A + W)$$

Moreover the inequality does not hold for the other posssible values for $D \neq I$